# Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'. in anguluar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

library:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/angularjs-social-login@2.6.1/angularjs-social-login.js"></script>
```

Facebook button

```
<button fb-login type="button">facebook</button>
```

in controller

```
app.config(function(socialProvider){
socialProvider.setFbKey({appId: "***************", apiVersion: "v2.4"});
});
```

**Reference**: https://github.com/heresy/angularjs-social-login-example/blob/master/index.html

Also, I have tried login with google and it's work and same as Facebook got the following error:

> Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=***************&domain=loca…lation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&sdk=joey&version=v2.4' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.

Comment: While you didn't provided any HTML, I suppose you're using an `iframe` which results in this error.

Comment: @fabrik I  m not using an iframe

Comment: @fabrik I have already  tried this but get a different error so I try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because Facebook is not allowing you to embed their login iframe directly on your page, you need to open a new window. Not too sure what goes on in the `fb-login` directive but you can try adding `target="_top"` to your button to load the Facebook login in its own window rather than in an iframe on the page. They set `X-Frame-Options` to `DENY` or `SAMEORIGIN` to prevent hijacking of user sessions by malicious sites.

```
<button fb-login type="button" target="_top">facebook</button>
```

Comment: I try this but same error btw thx for the response.

Comment: When does the error occur, on page load or on button click? And when you click the button does it try to open a new window?

Comment: when page load gets an error occurs and then click a button it's nothing response to work.and also not open window.

Comment: Upon further investigation it looks like this problem was brought up in the module's github. It was troubleshot a little then never resolved as far as I can tell. https://github.com/heresy/angularjs-social-login/issues/4 is the button nested within a `<frame>` or `<iframe>`?

Comment: i  have not used  <iframe> or <frame> tag in example.